# Are Mercurial Queue specific commands equivalent to Mercurial commands with a --mq parameter?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

I'm trying to learn Mercurial Queues and I'm confused by there being both a bunch of "hg q*" commands and also many normal hg commands with the "--mq" parameter.  I think that the --mq parameter is meant to replace some of the q* commands, but I'm not sure.  There doesn't seem to be a tutorial or documentation on the (new?) preferred methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `--mq` option affects all commands that take a repository as an argument -- it actually changes the targeted repo to be `$(hg root)/.hg/patches`, so it's effectively the same as running any mercurial command like this:

```
hg --repository $(hg root)/.hg/patches ....
```

Resultingly, every command that has a `-R/--repository` option has a --mq option and didn't need to be modified to get one.  Any command you've previously used in mercurial: commit, push, pull, summary, id, etc. can take `--mq`.  Here's the relevant python code:

```
def mqcommand(orig, ui, repo, *args, **kwargs):
    """Add --mq option to operate on patch repository instead of main"""

    # some commands do not like getting unknown options
    mq = kwargs.pop('mq', None)

    if not mq:
        return orig(ui, repo, *args, **kwargs)

    q = repo.mq
    r = q.qrepo()
    if not r:
        raise util.Abort(_('no queue repository'))
    return orig(r.ui, r, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: So in general the --mq option is only for versioning my patches?  It doesn't really replace any of the q* commands (except for maybe qinit)?

Comment: Correct.  If you're queue isn't versioned (but they all should be!) then push, pull, commit, clone, summary, etc. with the --mq option will exit saying no patch queue repository exists.

Answer (score 1):

The commands that the `--mq` flag make unnecessary have been marked deprecated so that they disappear from `hg help mq`. This is why `qcommit` and `qinit` no long show up.

You can still do `hg qcommit` to see the help for the command if you are curious.

Personally, I don't like the `--mq` flag. Instead I use a shell alias:

```
mq='hg -R $(hg root)/.hg/patches'
```

and then I can do `mq status`, `mq commit`, `mq push`, etc. I find that the distinction between the `hg` and `mq` command names match how I think of the operations. Note that this simple alias doesn't take multiple queues into account, so if you use `hg qqueue`, then you'll have to extend it a bit.